# I am trying to create an extension method but it is not spiting out the right info

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, extension-methods

I am trying to create an Extension Method, but it is not doing what I want it to do.

Here is my Extension Method

```
public static string StringOptional(this string StartString, string AddOnString, int Length, Utility.PaddingSide Side)
{
    string AddOnStringFormated;
    if (AddOnString != null)
    { AddOnStringFormated = Utility.FixedLengthString(AddOnString, Length, Side); }
    else
    {
        string AddOnStringBlank = "";
        AddOnStringFormated = Utility.FixedLengthString(AddOnStringBlank, Length, Side);
    }
    string FinishString = Utility.FormatString(StartString, AddOnStringFormated);
    return FinishString;
}
```

In my regular code

```
string LineTemp = "FirstLineOfCode";
string LineAdd = "SecondLine";
LineTemp.StringOptional(ImmOrNm, 23, Utility.PaddingSide.Right);
return LineTemp;
```

At the end LineTemp should have both strings formatted together, but it is not.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string is immutable you have to to

```
 LineTemp = LineTemp.StringOptional(ImmOrNm, 23, Utility.PaddingSide.Right);
```

Comment: I don't know how I overlooked that